# Danger of inserting knitting needles into an electrical outlet

Tags: ac, mains

When I was a little kid (read: inexperienced), a friend of mine claimed (as his mother warned him) that putting metallic things into an electrical outlet is dangerous. Kids are curious. In order to believe in the claim, I had to insert knitting needles into a typical USSR electrical outlet with two holes and without ground (Type C - CEE 7/16 Europlug).

I think we had the following mains electricity:

- Residential voltage 220V
- Three-Phase voltage 400V
- Frequency 50 Hz

The knitting needles looked like the image below: two metallic needles connected with a plastic tube. The length of the tube was about 0.5 meters (1.5 feet).

[image]

I felt how the current flowed through my arms and chest and I quickly removed the needles from the outlet. I felt "energized" (I assume it was just an adrenaline rush). During this dangerous experiment, the plastic tube burned right in the middle of its length.

Up to this day, I don't know the answer to the following question:
Why the plastic tube connecting the metallic needles burned right in the middle? I assume the plastic tube had zero conductivity.

Additionally, how come the little kid survived? Did the current split between two paths: hand-chest-hand and needle-tube-needle?

Please be an adult and respect others when answering.

Comment: not plastic tube ... metal cable

Comment: Nothing has zero conductivity, not even a vacuum, and even things with very low conductivity breakdown and become  conductive at a high enough voltage. Nor do things necessarily retain the same insulating characteristics after being exposed to a high voltage; they can be degraded. Just look at how lightning moves through the air with ease. Also, are you sure the it wasn't a plastic sheath around a metal cable?

Comment: Could be a lot of explanation. Water inside the tube one of them. And current trough the body depends on resistance. Dry skin high resistive. I got  zapped once it's 347V,  get away wi h burns only. Three phase voltage 380V.

Comment: Please avoid shocking yourself.  You may find [my answer to this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/553499/how-does-electricity-from-a-3-phase-4-wire-480y-277v-ev-meter-differ-from-a-stan/553594#553594) useful regarding the safety aspects of your question.  Some plastics are not good insulators.  Some are even decent conductors.  Notably, some people are fine after numerous low voltage (347V or less) shocks, some develop heart conditions, which may not be noticed, and some unlucky vulnerable folk are electrocuted by their first shock.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I am 95% sure that it was a plastic tube. It was hollow inside: just air. I cut it with scissors: it felt like plastics. I bent it: it felt like plastics.

Comment: @K H, I have a mild heart condition. Come to think of it, it could be related to the experiment.

Comment: You didn’t by chance get any Super Powers from this incident did you?

Comment: No spaces in an @ name, even if there are in the persons username, or the person doesn't get the @.

Comment: @jsotola, I am fairly confident that it was a plastic hollow tube. The image (with apparently metal cable) was provided just to give a general idea of the knitting needles.

Answer (score 5):

> Up to this day, I don't know the answer to the following question: Why the plastic tube connecting the metallic needles burned right in the middle? I assume the plastic tube had zero conductivity.

I'm guessing that it had a cable through the middle of it for strength, and the plastic tube on the outside protected the knitting from the cable.

> Additionally, how come the little kid survived? Did the current split between two paths: hand-chest-hand and needle-tube-needle?

Unless a fuse blew, you were exposed to 220V.  But 220V isn't instantly fatal -- you have to hang on for a while.  And whether it's fatal depends on skin conductivity.  Probably what happened was that your hands were dry, and your reflex to snatch the needles out of the socket was aided by the electric current contracting your biceps (which are stronger than your triceps, so you'd tend to convulse with your hands going toward your chest).

I'm sure it's strongly dis-recommended in any official channel, but when I was growing up the recommendation was that if you had 120V circuit and you didn't know if it was live you touched it with the *back* of your hand -- because if your hand closes that way, it closes away from the wire.  Touching a wire with your palm would make you involuntarily grab it, which leads to prolonged exposure to the current, and a higher chance of electrocution.

Comment: I remember some old-timer electricians sticking their finger in a light socket to see if the circuit was live

Comment: Not me!  I've touched enough live wires by mistake; I'm not going to do it on purpose.

Comment: Before toners and tracers were reasonably priced, I knew a few old journeyman who would "trace" an unknown circuit by shorting it to ground and seeing which breaker blew!

Comment: It was a plastic hollow tube filled with regular air. The fuse did not blow. Both my hands and the tube were dry.

Comment: One way or another, something was conductive.  I suspect additives in the plastic, but at this remove -- who knows?

Comment: electroboom just touches anything live. he do not care